# Error: must be str, not generator in Python

Tags: python

I am using python and here is a piece of my code:

```
wp = open(outfile, 'w')
fields = line.split('\t')
gene_ID = fields[0]
chr = fields[1]
strand = fields[2]
start = int(fields[3])
end = int(fields[4])
bc = {'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A', 'N':'N'}       
if strand == '+':
    wp.write(chr_string[start:end]) 
if strand == '-':
    newstart, newend = -(start + 1), -(end + 1)
    wp.write(bc[base.upper()] for base in chr_string[newstart:newend]) <--error pointed at this line
```

When I try to run my whole code, I get the following message:

```
TypeError: must be str, not generator
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code that is prompting this?

Comment: Well, it's pretty self-explanatory: You're passing a generator expression to `write`, when it's expecting a string...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bc[base.upper()] for base in chr_string[newstart:newend]` is a generator expression. 
You need to make a string from that via e.g. `join` method: `''.join(c[base.upper()] for base in chr_string[newstart:newend])`

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was missing! Do I need to do this on the strand == '+' as well?

Comment: No need, `chr_string[start:end]` is a slice of a string, thus also a string.